# Make regression model with categorical data with Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a CSV file with more than 10 columns, some of those columns have categorical data, some categorical columns has only `yes` and `no` values, some columns have colors (`green`, `blue`, `red`...) and some columns have other string values.

Is there a way to make the regression model with all columns?

I know that `yes` and `no` values can be represented as 1 and 0, but I have read that its not good to represent color names or city names with numbers.
Is there a better / correct way to do this?

This is the simple code with dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.DataFrame({'par1':[1,3,5,7,9, 11,13],
                   'par2':[0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 1, 1.2, 1.45],
                   'par3':['yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no'],
                   'par4':['blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'blue'],
                   'output':[103, 310, 522, 711, 921, 1241, 1451]})

print(df)

features = df.iloc[:,:-1]
result = df.iloc[:,-1]

reg = LinearRegression()
model = reg.fit(features, result)

prediction = model.predict([[2, 0.33, 'no', 'red']])

reg_score = reg.score(features, result)

print(prediction, reg_score)
```

In the real dataset that I'm using, those string values are very important to the dataset, so I can't just remove that column

Comment: I think the key word you are looking for is `one-hot encoding`, you can look for this on Google and find everything you need :)

Comment: use `pandas.dummies` on `par4` which is similar to one hot encoding

Comment: Multiple approaches are possible. You can also look for FeatureHasher in sklearn. Every approach has its own pros and cons. You can explore the official docs of sklearn for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically "[one-hot encode](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/)" categorical variables. This is also called "[adding dummy variables](https://stattrek.com/multiple-regression/dummy-variables.aspx)".

You will also want to "[standardize](https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/standardize-variables-regression/)" the numerical variables.

Scikit-learn makes this easy:

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

t = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(), ['par3', 'par4']),
    ('scale', StandardScaler(), ['par1', 'par2'])
], remainder='passthrough') # Default is to drop untransformed columns

t.fit_transform(df)
```

Finally, you'll need to transform your input in the same way before running it through the model.

Bringing it all together you get:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler


df = pd.DataFrame({'par1':[1,3,5,7,9, 11,13],
                   'par2':[0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 1, 1.2, 1.45],
                   'par3':['yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no'],
                   'par4':['blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'blue'],
                   'output':[103, 310, 522, 711, 921, 1241, 1451]})

t = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(), ['par3', 'par4']),
    ('scale', StandardScaler(), ['par1', 'par2'])
], remainder='passthrough')

# Transform the features
features = t.fit_transform(df.iloc[:,:-1])
result = df.iloc[:,-1]

# Train the linear regression model
reg = LinearRegression()
model = reg.fit(features, result)

# Generate a prediction
example = t.transform(pd.DataFrame([{
    'par1': 2, 'par2': 0.33, 'par3': 'no', 'par4': 'red'
}]))
prediction = model.predict(example)
reg_score = reg.score(features, result)
print(prediction, reg_score)
```

Comment: Why do I need ColumnTransformer, can I just do OneHotEncoder()?

Also, this transforms my hole dataset not just categorical columns?

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that one would typically also rescale the numeric features with `StandardScaler`

Comment: What do you mean `It's maybe worth noting that one would typically also rescale the numeric features with StandardScaler`, I did not understand you.
Should I use `one hot encoder` or standard scaler?

Comment: I've added code for this and a link that hopefully provides some background!

Comment: can you please write this answer in full code because im getting an error `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200165/discussion-between-taga-and-joe-halliwell).

Comment: @Also do I need to pass `example = t.transform(pd.DataFrame([{
    'par1': 2, 'par2': 0.33, 'par3': 'no', 'par4': 'red'
}]))` as dataframe or I can just pass a list [2,0.33,'no', 'red']

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a general question about regression, not just regarding SciKit, so I'll try to answer in general terms.

You are right about yes/no variables, you can encode them as binary variables, 0 and 1. But, the same principle holds for colors and other categorical variables:

You create `n-1` dummy binary variables, `n` being the number of categories. Each of the dummy variables is basically saying whether your observation falls into the corresponding category. You declare one of the them, e.g. blue, to be the default category, and encode it by setting all dummy variables to zero. I.e. if it is neither red, nor green, nor any other available color, it must be blue.

The other categories are encoded by setting the corresponding dummy variable to `1` and leaving all others at zero. So for `red` you could set `dummy1 = 1`, for `green` `dummy2 = 1` etc.

Binary variables are just a special case of this encoding, where you have two categories, which you encode with 1 (= 2-1) variable.